# Can we pass C# delegate as a method parameter? If so how to pass an argument?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following code snippet with me.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int[] items;
    public unsafe T DoSomething<T>(delegate*<int[], T> abc)
    {
        return abc(items);
    }
}
```

I want to pass `HowToDoSomething(int[] values)` to above the `Dosomething` method without using `Func`.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myItems= { 1, 2, 3, 4};
            SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(myItems);

            //How to call DoSomething here with delegate*<int[], T>
            //without using changing DoSomething signature with Func
        }

        public static int HowToDoSomething(int[] values)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

P.S. What does the asterisk symbol does in `public unsafe T DoSomething<T>(delegate*<int[], T> abc)`? Is it a type pattern?

UPDATE:

I tried below yet I am a stuck atm on figuring out how to pass the delegate to sc.DoSomething

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] myItems= { 1, 2, 3, 4};
                SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(myItems);

                HowToDoSomethingDelegate hwtdsd = new HowToDoSomethingDelegate(HowToDoSomething);
                

                //How to call DoSomething here with delegate*<int[], T>
                //without using changing DoSomething signature with Func
            }
    
            public static int HowToDoSomething(int[] values)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            public delegate int HowToDoSomethingDelegate(int[] vs)
        }
```

Comment: `Func` is a delegate You can declare your own delegates.

Comment: The asterisk is a pointer ([docs on pointers, unsafe code, etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code)). You generally have no need to even think about pointers in C#.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama how can I declare my own delegate to  HowToDoSomething and pass it to DoSomething?

Comment: These things _are_ [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). Note the link on the left to "Using delegates" too.

Comment: Sorry, is `DoSomething` your method, or a method you can't change? I don't see why it needs to be `delegate*<int[], T>` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method

```
public unsafe T DoSomething<T>(delegate*<int[], T> abc)
{
    return abc(items);
}
```

the expected argument `abc` is defined as a **pointer to a delegate** that expects an argument of type `int[]` and returns a value of type `T`.

The asterisk has the meaning "pointer to". Pointers can only be used in an `unsafe` context. That's why the method `DoSomething` is marked as `unsafe`.

In order to call the method and pass your own method as a pointer, you need to

1. perform the call in an unsafe context using the `unsafe` keyword and
2. use the ampersand symbol `&` to get the pointer to your method. The ampersand has the meaning "get pointer for" / "get address of".

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
    unsafe
    {
        c.DoSomething<int>(&HowToDoSomething);
    }
}

public static int HowToDoSomething(int[] values)
{
    return 1;
}
```

---

Now why you would want to use pointers and unsafe code is a question that needs answering. Using unsafe code carries lots of risks and has very few advantages.

Comment: I guess it might be worth adding that you could swap out the delegate using `ref` rather than pointers, if that's the reason why OP is doing this. Though even that seems like an odd use case.

Comment: @NineBerry Thanks, this explains it. So there's no need to create a separate delegate to point the function but can use the ampersand to directly pass the pointer.  Does this mean &HowToDoSomething is type of delegate?

Comment: C# will automatically create delegates from methods in the right context.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the noise. Just figured that.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `Func`:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(Func<int[],T> abc)
{
    return abc(items);
}
```

you can do this :

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
string s = sc.DoSomething<string>((items) =>
{
   return "Hello";
});
```

Comment: OP asks for `unsafe` / and pointers... Make sure to clarify how your safe/non-pointers example is answering the question.